# Add custom tags in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch, and I am exploring whether it is a viable solution for my needs, which I shall explain below. Greatly appreciate any guidance from the experts.

I have a large amount of text data, running into hundreds of millions of documents. I would like to identify a subset of these files (could be thousands to hundreds of thousands), that contain specific keywords in these files (say drug names), and add custom tags to associate with the result set. For example, say 100K files identified as having "drug-A-for-Diabetes", should be associated with tag "drug-A". Is ES the right solution for this problem? I understand ES is highly scalable, but for a workflow like this, is scalabiity a concern? I am at a point where I am exploring a few alternatives, and given the time constraints, was hoping to get some guidance before diving deeper (I am still going through the documentation to better understand the Elastic Stack). Would be grateful for any guidance/pointers that would take us in the right direction.

Comment: If you manage to find a query to identify all document related to "drug A for diabetes", then you can easily tag them with "drug-A". A tag is just another field in your documents on which you can then run a term filter in order to select all the documents about "drug A for diabetes" and perform other kind of aggregations, etc. Your use case is not 100% clear to me, but from what I can read, yes ES supports that. Will it suit your exact need (current and future), no idea without diving further.

Comment: @Val Thanks a lot for the pointers. I shall look up on filters and aggregations to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch could be used for this. There are a few different approaches you could take. For example, you could index the documents, then post-indexing query for keywords and update the document(s) with the appropriate tag(s). Or you could leverage pipelines, tagging the documents as they are sent to elasticsearch indexing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response @hudsonb. Greatly appreciate it.